# why gRPC server only send 8k data frame and block for ack?

Tags: grpc, grpc-go

in my case. nginx is 172.26.1.219 , backend server is 172.16.2.93.the rtt between nginx and server is about 200ms.
[ [wireshark analyse for the gRPC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJnWH.jpg)

As the picture above, the backend server send 4 frame with 2890 size util it recieved the ack frame. My backend server is build on gRPC-go,is there any way to let the server send all the data frame in one rtt?

Comment: There might be 3 factors to consider here: 1. MTU; 2. flow control; 3. Go's behavior of combining small messages. For flow control, gRPC can only one 1 outstanding write, this prevents the peer from getting overwhelmed.

Comment: One thing to try is the write buffer size https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#WriteBufferSize